# Material UI: best way to set elements side by side

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using Material UI to style an ecommerce project. I'm trying to figure out how to make all of the elements (Typography, Buttons) display side by side in a row instead of vertically.

Is there a way to do this simply with material UI? Should I add CSS? I previously tried adding each element to a Grid item within a Container, it kind of worked (couldn't center), but doesn't seem like the right approach for this scenario.

If you see my screenshot below, I'm trying to set "T-Shirt Twilight", the image, "$49.99", the quantity input buttons and "Remove" side by side horizontally.

**Elements I'm trying to set side by side:**

```
  <div className="App">
        {products.map((item, index) => (

          <Grid container item xs={12}>
            <Grid item xs={1} />
            <Grid item xs={10}>

                <Grid item xs={12} container key={item.id}>
                    <Grid item xs={1} />
                    <Grid item xs={10}>

                      <Typography>{item.title}</Typography>
                      <img src={require(`../images/${item.image}`)} className={classes.productImage}></img>
                      <Typography>${(item.quantity * item.price).toFixed(2)}</Typography>

                      <ButtonGroup size="small">
                        <Button type="button" onClick={item.quantity > 1 ? () => decreaseQuantity(index) : null}>-</Button>
                        <Button>{item.quantity}</Button>
                        <Button type="button" onClick={() => increaseQuantity(index)}>+</Button>
                      </ButtonGroup>

                      <Button
                        onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>
                      Remove
                      </Button>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={1} />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </div>
```

**Screenshot for reference:**
[image]

**Full code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './../App.css';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { getQuantity, getTotal } from '../helpers/helperTools';
import {Grid, Typography,useMediaQuery, useTheme, Container, Button, ButtonGroup} from '@material-ui/core';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    productImage: {
      maxWidth: '20%'
}
}))

function Cart({ setQty: setParentQty }) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    function updateQty(products){
        /* var holder = 0;
        products.forEach((a, b) => {
          holder = holder + a.quantity
        })*/
        // setQty({quantity: holder})
        // localStorage.setItem('quantity', JSON.stringify({ quantity: newQty }))
        setParentQty({ quantity: getQuantity(products) });
      }

    useEffect(function() {
      const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product'));
      const products = storageItems || [];
      setProducts(products);
      updateQty(products);
    }, []);

    function decreaseQuantity(index) {
      if (products[index]){
        const newProducts = products.map((a, b) => {
          if (b === index) return {...a, quantity: a.quantity - 1}
          else return a
        });

        setProducts(newProducts);
        localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(newProducts))
        updateQty(newProducts)
      }
    }

    function increaseQuantity(index) {
        if (!products[index]) return;

        const newProducts = products.map((a, b) => {
          if (b === index) return {...a, quantity: a.quantity + 1}
          else return a
        })

        setProducts(newProducts)
        localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(newProducts))
        updateQty(newProducts);
    }

    function removeItem(index){
      const product = products[index];

      if (!product) return;

      const newProducts = products.filter((v, z) => z !== index);
      setProducts(newProducts);

      localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(newProducts));

      updateQty(newProducts);
    }

     if (products.length === 0) {
       return (
         <div className="App">
          <p>
            Cart Empty
          </p>
          <Link to={`/`}>
          <p>Continue shopping</p>
          </Link>
         </div>)
     }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {products.map((item, index) => (

          <Grid container item xs={12}>
            <Grid item xs={1} />
            <Grid item xs={10}>

                <Grid item xs={12} container key={item.id}>
                    <Grid item xs={1} />
                    <Grid item xs={10}>

                      <Typography>{item.title}</Typography>
                      <img src={require(`../images/${item.image}`)} className={classes.productImage}></img>
                      <Typography>${(item.quantity * item.price).toFixed(2)}</Typography>

                      <ButtonGroup size="small">
                        <Button type="button" onClick={item.quantity > 1 ? () => decreaseQuantity(index) : null}>-</Button>
                        <Button>{item.quantity}</Button>
                        <Button type="button" onClick={() => increaseQuantity(index)}>+</Button>
                      </ButtonGroup>

                      <Button
                        onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>
                      Remove
                      </Button>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={1} />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </div>

    );
}

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use inline style for it. I also removed some unnecessary grid items. May be you want to grid more about [breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#grid-api) in Grid. Working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-forked-37bi7?file=/index.js)

```
    <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={1} />
          <Grid item xs={10} style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
            <Typography>{item.title}</Typography>
            <img src={item.image} className={classes.productImage}></img>
            <Typography>${(item.quantity * item.price).toFixed(2)}</Typography>

            <ButtonGroup size="small">
              <Button
                type="button"
                onClick={
                  item.quantity > 1 ? () => decreaseQuantity(index) : null
                }
              >
                -
              </Button>
              <Button>{item.quantity}</Button>
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => increaseQuantity(index)}>
                +
              </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>

            <Button onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>Remove</Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={1} />
        </Grid>
```